# let f and g be real functions. if 2f-3g is continuous at 1 and 3f-2g is continuous at 1 so f and g are continuous at 1

Tags: calculus, continuity

I don't know if this is true or not, I tried to prove and I didn't succeed and the I tried to give a counter example and I also failed.
so can someone please help

Comment: **Hint :** $$g=\dfrac{2}{5} \times (3f-2g)-\dfrac{3}{5} \times (2f-3g)$$